# postgresqlの「::bpchar」について

Tags: postgresql

こんにちは、さっそくですが質問させていただきます。
とあるテーブルのindexを貼り直しているのですが

```
"table_name_login_idx" btree (login) WHERE sex = 'm'::bpchar
```

とありますが、この`::bpchar`ってどういうことでしょうか？
sexはcharacter(1)です。

ご指導お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL において、コロン2つ `::` は型のキャストを表します。つまりここでは `'m'` を `bpchar` 型にキャストしています。

`bpchar` 型とは "blank-padded char" を表す型で、`character(n)` の内部的な名前です。`varchar(n)` や `text` とは[別の型](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html)です。

この型キャストがないと `'m'` の型が一旦 [`unknown`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-pseudo.html) として解釈されてしまうので、明示的に型キャストしているのでしょう。

参考

- [PostgreSQL Documentation 4.2.9 Type Casts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS)
- [Why char datatype is converted to bpchar automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51421269/5989200)

Comment: あのmはcharacter(1)で、character(n)も同じ型ではないんでしょうか

Comment: @こばやし1 さん、追記しました。